# properties of the solution to an ordinary differential equation with bounded lower semicontinuous right hand side

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I have the differential equation
$\dot{x}=f(x)$
where f is bounded and is lower semicontinuous on $x\in R$. Can we say in general that the solution $x(t)$ to this differential equation is continuous. Can we say anything about the smoothness of the solution.

Comment: It all depends on how pathological your $f$ can be - is there any characterisation of such functions? I think you might be able to guarantee the global existence of the solution.